# Flask / jinja how to calculate average

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to study jinja / flash / python combination, but having problems. I found this kind of example from the internet and got it working nicely, but now i'd want to improve the code and dont know how. I tried many different kind of actions to print the average of grades that are given by user, but can't get it to work.

anyone know how to help?

grades.html

```
<form action = "result" method = "POST">
   <p>Name <input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
   <p>Gymnastics <input type = "text" name = "Gymnastics" /></p>
   <p>English <input type = "text" name = "English" /></p>
   <p>Maths <input type ="text" name = "Maths" /></p>
   <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
</form>
```

result.html

```
    <!doctype html>
  <table border = 1>
    {% for key, value in result.items() %}


    <tr>
       <th> {{ key }} </th>
       <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}


 </table>
```

app.py

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def student():
   return render_template('grades.html')


@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)
```

Ok so it's working nicely, but how can I improve my code and print the average of all these posted grades?

Comment: You can calculate the average in your `result` function and add to the a `result` dictionary consisting of the previous fields and send it to the template

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the grades add them up and divide by the number of grades. Or you could use the [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function:

```
import statistics

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    subjects = ['Gymnastics', 'English', 'Maths']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form.to_dict()
        average = statistics.mean([float(result[subject]) for subject in subjects])
        result['average'] = f'{average:.2f}'
        return render_template("result.html",result = result)
```

This code extracts the grades for each known subject and converts them to float values. The average is calculated, converted to a string to 2 decimal places, and placed into the `result` dict so that it is available in the template.

The template will display the result, however, you might want to format it more nicely.